# How is the password prompt going to protect me from ruining my computer?

Tags: operating-systems, authentication, access-control, unix

On Unix based systems, I'm often prompted to enter my password before installing or running a program.

Why does this protect me?

If I'm running a kiosk, I understand that a password might prevent *someone else* from messing with my computer. However, on my own computer, if I want to install something, entering my password won't stop me from running a virus or malicious program.

Comment: This is also similar to UAC in Windows 7 (and Vista), depending on settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prompting you to enter password is necessary to login into *root* account, enable user with higher rights. This is done just to prevent user from accidental actions like invalid command "*rm -rf /*". Sitting all the time under the *root* is not good idea - you really does not need such rights all the time you work. Also, it stops, prevents and decreases malicious stuff impact.

It is a part of Unix security model's philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

That protects you because someone can't just pass by your system and install a malware unless they know your password. (General example)

And it also has the benefit of reminding you that what you are doing might mess up your computer ;)

Comment: Isn't your answer similar to my "kiosk" example?

Comment: Yes, but you seem to forget that, unless your computer is in a bank safe somewhere in a concrete cage, someone can have physical access to it at one point or another